# Conservation of momentum of a bob attached to ceiling with string taut

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

In this question a bob(mass m) is tied to a string of length 5m and is attached to the ceiling. It is then released and hits the floor at a distance of 4m from the ceiling. What will be the maximum height it will attain after colliding and when the string again becomes taut. (e=0 for the floor) [image: you can see the situation in this image]

I calculated the velocity just before it hits the floor using energy conservation. And the velocity along the normal will be zero as it collides inelastically. But I can't think further how to calculate the velocity just before the bob leaves the ground again.

Comment: If the collision with the floor is perfectly inelastic, the bob doesn't leave the floor at all - it just hits the ground and sticks there. If the collision is perfectly elastic, it bounces off at the same speed it landed, at an angle equal to the incident angle mirrored around the vertical..

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I think it won't stick to the ground because it strikes it at an angle and only the velocity in y axis should be zero that is along the normal and it should continue to move in the x direction. It won't stick because it's not head on collision. Correct me please if i am wrong.

Comment: It depends on the material, not the angle of contact - a rubber ball won't stick to the ground no matter how you drop it, but a sticky ball of tape will. The inelastic problem isn't very interesting as the ball doesn't go anywhere, so the problem seems to imply an elastic collision. The ball is moving both vertically and horizontally at the time of impact - in an elastic collision with a horizontal surface, the horizontal velocity will remain the same and the vertical velocity will change sign, yielding the same overall speed at collision and rebound.